# Como obter distância dadas as coordenadas usando SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, geolocalização

Estou fazendo uma função em [php](/questions/tagged/php), na qual, dada uma coordenada GPS, ele buscará no banco de dados os locais registrados, que não são necessariamente fixos, dentro de uma determinada distância.

A minha dúvida é: como calculo a distância entre as coordenadas passadas e a coordenada registrada no banco de dados?

Dado que, possuo a seguinte função em `PHP` que calcula a distância entre duas coordenadas:

```php
function calcDistancia($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2)
{
    $d2r = 0.017453292519943295769236;

    $dlong = ($long2 - $long1) * $d2r;
    $dlat = ($lat2 - $lat1) * $d2r;

    $temp_sin = sin($dlat/2.0);
    $temp_cos = cos($lat1 * $d2r);
    $temp_sin2 = sin($dlong/2.0);

    $a = ($temp_sin * $temp_sin) + ($temp_cos * $temp_cos) * ($temp_sin2 * $temp_sin2);
    $c = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0 - a));

    return 6368.1 * $c;
}
```

E não estou conseguindo traduzir para uma expressão do tipo:

```sql
SELECT cidade.cid_id 
FROM cidade 
WHERE (expressão) < $distance
```

O que me sugerem?

---

Outra alternativa seria buscar todos os locais usando SQL (como tradicional) e verificar as distâncias usando PHP. Mas fico na dúvida, há alguma diferença no desempenho em relação a abordagem anterior?

Comment: Não seria mais viável ter uma tabela com a distância entre cada cidade?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Não seria possível pois os valores seriam dinâmicos. A cidade nesse caso é só ilustrativo, estou trabalhando com "locais", que podem não ser fixos.

Comment: Implemente esta função no banco (stored function) e use seu comando SQL normalmente. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: Outro ponto a considerar é o que o MySQL possui uma extensão para trabalhar com dados espaciais: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Primeira essa função em PHP está incorreta (talvez tenha sido adaptada de uma versão em C++?). Uma versão corrigida é:

```php
function calcDistancia($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2)
{
    $d2r = 0.017453292519943295769236;

    $dlong = ($long2 - $long1) * $d2r;
    $dlat = ($lat2 - $lat1) * $d2r;

    $temp_sin = sin($dlat/2.0);
    $temp_cos = cos($lat1 * $d2r);
    $temp_sin2 = sin($dlong/2.0);

    $a = ($temp_sin * $temp_sin) + ($temp_cos * $temp_cos) * ($temp_sin2 * $temp_sin2);
    $c = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1.0 - $a));

    return 6368.1 * $c;
}
```

Com essa versão, fiz o seguinte teste:

```php
echo '1: ' . calcDistancia(-11.531371, -46.559372, -11.686069, -46.305313) . "\n";
echo '2: ' . calcDistancia(-23.524487, -47.441711, -23.549078,-46.614304) . "\n";
```

E o resultado foi:

> 1: 32.574603346655
>
> 2: 84.362785480187

**Nota:** no teste 2, coloquei a distância de Sorocaba até São Paulo. O resultado parece bem satisfatório, pois de carro a distância é de aproximadamente 100km, mas em linha reta é realmente algo entre 80 a 90.

### [Veja o código no Codepad](http://codepad.org/ifNaz5vP)

---

Com base nisso, fiz a seguinte função MySQL:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION DISTANCIA(
  lat1 DOUBLE, 
  long1 DOUBLE, 
  lat2 DOUBLE, 
  long2 DOUBLE) 
RETURNS DOUBLE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE d2r DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlong DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlat DOUBLE;
    DECLARE temp_sin DOUBLE;
    DECLARE temp_cos DOUBLE;
    DECLARE temp_sin2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE a DOUBLE;
    DECLARE c DOUBLE;

    set d2r = 0.017453292519943295769236;

    set dlong = (long2 - long1) * d2r;
    set dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * d2r;

    set temp_sin = sin(dlat/2.0);
    set temp_cos = cos(lat1 * d2r);
    set temp_sin2 = sin(dlong/2.0);

    set a = (temp_sin * temp_sin) + (temp_cos * temp_cos) * (temp_sin2 * temp_sin2);
    set c = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0 - a));

    return 6368.1 * c;

END//
```

Testei a função da seguinte forma:

```sql
select 
  DISTANCIA(-11.531371, -46.559372, -11.686069, -46.305313) as '1',
  DISTANCIA(-23.524487, -47.441711, -23.549078,-46.614304) as '2';
```

E o resultado foi:

```
1                  2
32.574603346655    84.362785480187
```

***O mesmo do PHP!***

### [Veja o Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e49f/2)

---

#### Atualização

A resposta do Paulo Rodrigues contém um método de cálculo *inline* (sem função) mais simples e com resultado muito próximo ao da função.

Fiz um [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/33455) para o teste #2 (Sorocaba/São Paulo) da seguinte forma:

```sql
select 6371 * 
    acos(
        cos(radians(-23.524487)) * 
        cos(radians(-23.549078)) * 
        cos(radians(-47.441711) - radians(-46.614304)) + 
        sin(radians(-23.524487)) *
        sin(radians(-23.549078))
    )
```

Obtive o valor `84.393323136458`. Não é o mesmo resultado da função e não sei qual está mais correto, porém é uma forma muito mais simples e com boa aproximação!

---

### Considerações de Desempenho

A função acima faz o cálculo bem e não será muito ineficiente porque não faz acesso à base. O problema é que ela exige a varredura de todas as linhas da tabela (*table scan*), já que não será usado nenhum índice. O mesmo ocorre com a fórmula da atualização acima.

#### Tabela auxiliar

Se a ideia é calcular a distância entre duas cidades já conhecidas e cadastradas no banco de dados, você pode criar uma tabela auxiliar cuja PK é composta por duas FKs para a cidade, mais um campo com a distância entre as duas. É como se cidade tivesse um relacionamento `N:N` com ela mesma. Essa tabela teria a distância calculada entre todas as cidades.

Obviamente isso vai exigir uma tabela com bastante registros. O número de cidades ao quadrado, mais precisamente.

#### Limitar a consulta a faixas de coordenadas

Esta seria uma abordagem híbrida, um pouco parecida com a ideia do @Miguel Angelo.

Ao invés de aplicar a função de distância para localizar cidades próximas comparando todas as cidades, primeiro verifique se o valor absoluto das coordenadas está razoavelmente próximo.

Suponha que você queira buscar a coordenada `-23.524487, -47.441711`. Então, filtre as cidades cujas coordenadas estão próximas a `23` e `47`, depois aplique a função para obter o resultado mais preciso.

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT cidade.cid_id 
  FROM cidade 
 WHERE cidade.latitude BETWEEN ($lat - $distance / 111.19) AND ($lat + $distance / 111.19)
   and cidade.longitude BETWEEN ($long - $distance / 111.19) AND ($long + $distance / 111.19)
   and distancia(cidade.latitude, cidade.longitude,  (expressão) < $distance
```

As duas primeiras cláusulas irão filtrar a latidade e a longitude. Se você criar um índice para essas colunas, esse filtro será muito eficiente.

**Note que na comparação da `$distancia` com o valor em graus decimais, eu dividi a distância pela constante mágica `111.19` para fazer a conversão do valor em uma aproximação "bruta", isto é, que não leva em conta a curvatura da terra.**

Depois, a função `distancia()` irá melhorar os resultados, pois ao invés de recuperar um "quadrado" geométrico cujas pontas não respeitam a distância, os resultados estarão dentro do círculo cujo raio é a distância.

Comment: Realmente, eu já possuía uma versão implementada em outro programa em C++. Posso editar a função da pergunta ou deixo como está?

Comment: @LucasNunes Por mim eu editaria, mas fica a seu critério, acho que todos conseguiram pegar a ideia.

Comment: Uma dúvida (vale para a resposta do @Miguel Angelo também), nesse último caso (da busca por faixas de coordenadas), `$distance` deve ser dado em graus decimais, certo? Por exemplo, se eu quero buscar para uma distancia 5km, eu devo converter 5km para graus decimais?

Comment: @LucasNunes Realmente isso passou despercebido. Teria, sim,  que aplicar um fator para transformar a distância em graus decimais. Como é em linha reta, seria muito mais simples. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @LucasNunes Após sua excelente observação, fiz a atualização ajustando o valor da distância para graus decimais de uma forma simplista.

Answer (score 5):

Em *MySQL*, eu tenho algo assim (não utilizando *functions*), passando `-19.83996, -43.94910`, por exemplo:

```
6371 * acos(cos(radians(-19.83996)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(-43.94910) - radians(lng)) + sin(radians(-19.83996)) * sin(radians(lat)))
```

Comment: +1 Executei num [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/33455) para o teste #2 que fiz na minha resposta e obtive `84.393323136458`. Não é o mesmo resultado e não sei qual está mais correto, porém é um método muito mais simples e com boa aproximação!

Answer (score 5):

Eu não calcularia a distância no banco de dados não. Ao invés disso, eu pegaria todos os pontos que estivesses dentro de um quadrado, que facilita a query, e ainda pode fazê-la muito mais rápida pois só usa operadores de maior-que `>` e menor-que `<`, e então depois de retornados os resultados para o PHP, ai sim, selecionaria aqueles que tivesses dentro de um certa distância.

Exemplo: Suponha que as coordenadas do GPS sejam `$x`, `$y`, que a distância máxima seja `$d`. Então a query ficaria assim:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coordX > '.($x-$d).' and coordX < '.($x+$d).
    ' and coordY > '.($y-$d).' and coordY < '.($y+$d);
```

Dessa forma a query vai rodar muito mais rápido. Ai então basta usar a função de calcular distâncias no PHP para que ao invés de retornar tudo que estiver dentro do quadrado, seja retornado tudo que estiver dentro do círculo.

Comment: É uma abordagem interessante se houver muitos dados na base. Mas por recuperar um **quadrado**, a acurácia do resultado não será tão boa.

Comment: Mas ai é só filtrar no PHP como eu disse. O SQL retorna os que estiverem dentro do quadrado, e depois o PHP filtra os que estiverem dentro do círculo.

Comment: Sim, sim, não tinha visto a atualização ao final. De qualquer forma, dei +1 porque essa solução permite a otimização por índices.

Answer (score 2):

Caso você possa criar uma function em seu banco, vai depender de qual banco está usando, você poderia fazer os cálculos por ela.

Em PLSQL ficaria assim

```
create or replace
FUNCTION CALCULA_DISTACIA_COORD 
(
    LATITUDE1 IN NUMBER,    
    LONGITUDE1 IN NUMBER,   
    LATITUDE2 IN NUMBER,    
    LONGITUDE2 IN NUMBER    
) RETURN NUMBER AS
    GRAU_RAD NUMBER := 0.0174532925;
    DIST_LATITUDE NUMBER;
    DIST_LONGITUDE NUMBER;
    DISTANCIA NUMBER;
    COEFF_A NUMBER;
    LATITUDE1_RAD NUMBER;   
    LONGITUDE1_RAD NUMBER;  
    LATITUDE2_RAD NUMBER;   
    LONGITUDE2_RAD NUMBER;
BEGIN
    --Conversao de graus para radiandos
    LATITUDE1_RAD   := LATITUDE1 * GRAU_RAD; 
    LONGITUDE1_RAD  := LONGITUDE1 * GRAU_RAD; 
    LATITUDE2_RAD   := LATITUDE2 * GRAU_RAD; 
    LONGITUDE2_RAD  := LONGITUDE2 * GRAU_RAD; 

    DIST_LATITUDE := LATITUDE2_RAD - LATITUDE1_RAD;
    DIST_LONGITUDE := LONGITUDE2_RAD - LONGITUDE1_RAD;
    COEFF_A := power(sin(DIST_LATITUDE/2),2)+cos(LATITUDE1_RAD)*cos(LATITUDE2_RAD)*power(sin(DIST_LONGITUDE/2),2);

    --Calculo da distancia em metros. Valor multiplicado por 6378140, que indica o raio da terra em metros
    DISTANCIA := 6378140*(2*atan2(sqrt(COEFF_A), sqrt(1 - COEFF_A)));

    RETURN DISTANCIA;
END CALCULA_DISTACIA_COORD;
```

Aparentemente é possível [criar functions nas versões mais recentes do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html), mas nunca testei isso.

Se for possível, você chama a function diretamente no select...

Answer (score 1):

Trabalho com dados geoespaciais e o mysql já tem suporte a geolocalização. Neste caso basta utilizar a função [`st_distance`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance):

```
ST_Distance(Point(lon1, lat1), Point(lon2,lat2))
```

Answer (score 1):

segue a função do calculo de distancia do "utluiz" para Swift:

```
func calculateDistanceFromCoordinate(_latOrigem: Double, _lngOrigem: Double, _latDestino: Double, _lngDestino: Double) -> Double {
    let d2r: Double = 0.017453292519943295769236

    let dlong: Double = (_lngDestino - _lngOrigem) * d2r
    let dlat: Double = (_latDestino - _latOrigem) * d2r

    let temp_sin: Double = sin(dlat/2.0)
    let temp_cos: Double = cos(_latOrigem * d2r)
    let temp_sin2: Double = sin(dlong/2.0)

    let a: Double = (temp_sin * temp_sin) + (temp_cos * temp_cos) * (temp_sin2 * temp_sin2)
    let c: Double = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0 - a))

    return 6368.1 * c;
}

//Exemplo:
let distance: Double = calculateDistanceFromCoordinate(-11.531371, _lngOrigem: -46.559372, _latDestino: -11.686069, _lngDestino: -46.305313)
```