# Como buscar por distância

Tags: sql, algoritmo, geometria

Tenho uma base de dados com coordenadas de diversos locais. Gostaria de saber como, a partir de uma localização informada, obter somente os locais que se encontra até determinada distância.

Vi uma pergunta similar: [Como obter distância dadas as coordenadas usando SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9128/como-obter-dist%C3%A2ncia-dadas-as-coordenadas-usando-sql) Porém, a resposta diz respeito a encontrar a distância específica de dois locais informados. Gostei das respostas naquela pergunta, mas acredito que deve haver um algoritmo mais apropriada para busca. Algo do tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE ((@lat - foo.lat)^2 + (@long - foo.long)^2)^(1/2) < @bar
```

Eu sei que essa não é a sintaxe correta para exponenciações no SQL. Meu maior problema com a fórmula acima, porém, é que ela só deve ser correta para distâncias relativamente pequenas, ou para um planeta plano.

A fórmula que procuro existe? Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Mas não é exatamente isso que tem na pergunta que você linkou? Na resposta do utluiz tem uma função sql para calcular a distância.

Comment: @bfavaretto as funções de busca que vi nas respostas buscam dentro de um quadrados. E isso se torna mais impreciso a medida que a distância aumenta. Eu gostaria uma fórmula que realmente obtivesse qualquer registro até determinada distância de um ponto informado, pra isso teria que ser uma estrutura mais complexa do que um quadrado ou um círculo - uma calota.

Comment: Você deve estar se confundindo, veja a função sql na resposta do utluiz. A fórmula inclusive usa o raio da Terra! É para cálculo numa esfera (e é um pouco imprecisa porque o planeta não é uma esfera perfeita, mas é suficiente para a maioria dos usos). Por favor me dê um retorno sobre o assunto, pretendo fechar esta pergunta como duplicata.

Comment: Ok, revi e concordo. Pode fechar :)